# Custom Timer job throws an error : "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString"

Tags: development, timer-jobs

I am facing an issue while trying to write the custom Timer Job in SharePoint 2007.

Have overridden the Execute method

```
public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
    {
        using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://esssharepoint20"))
        {
            oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList splist = oSPWeb.Lists["PhoneBook"];

                SPListItem spItem = splist.Items.Add();

                spItem["PhoneNumber"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                spItem.SystemUpdate();

            }
            oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }

    }
```

and registering the Job using a Feature

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        //string oSPsiteURL = (properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite).Url;

        using (SPSite phoneBookSite = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
        {
            SPWebApplication phoneBookApplication = phoneBookSite.WebApplication;
            SPJobDefinitionCollection timerJobCollection = phoneBookApplication.JobDefinitions;

            SPDailySchedule jobSchedule = new SPDailySchedule();

            jobSchedule.BeginHour = 0;
            jobSchedule.BeginMinute = 0;
            jobSchedule.BeginSecond = 0;

            jobSchedule.EndHour = 2;
            jobSchedule.EndMinute = 30;
            jobSchedule.EndSecond = 0;

           phoneBookPurgeData phoneBookTimerObj = new phoneBookPurgeData(
                "PhoneBook Timer Job",
                phoneBookApplication
                );

            phoneBookTimerObj.Schedule = jobSchedule;

            timerJobCollection.Add(phoneBookTimerObj);
            phoneBookApplication.Update();

        }
        //throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
```

however it throws the below error:

08/09/2011 22:29:30.60  Timer                   7psa    Critical    The Execute method of job definition PhoneBookTimerJob.phoneBookPurgeData (ID 2519a803-af39-4a2a-ae42-8d177a609ed8) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: uriString

08/09/2011 22:29:30.60  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x097C)                       0x0C7C  Windows SharePoint Services     Timer                           72ae    Unexpected  Exception stack trace:    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl)     at PhoneBookTimerJob.phoneBookPurgeData.Execute(Guid contentDbId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)

Webapplication is still exists, what am I doing wrong? and how to fix this?

Comment: Could you post data on the custom class phoneBookPurgeData as it seems this is what fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fighting with the error created a new dll with the same code and it works like a champ.

Comment: i made a small mistake while building the dll first time and kept it in the GAC. However realised and re-compiled, removed the old dll from the GAC, restarted IIS and added the updated dll into the Gac but still it was refering to the old dll and ended up with creating a new dll.

Comment: When working with timer jobs you have to restart the SharePoint Timer Service for your changes to take effect. Restarting the IIS won't help much, as the DLLs are loaded and cached by the timer service.
To restart the service, you can call "net stop sptimerv3" and "net start sptimerv3". For SharePoint 2010 it's "sptimerv4".

Answer (score 0):

Check that the site exist in PowerShell or in a console application

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://esssharepoint20
```

Just to be sure

Comment: If it wasn't there it would throw a FileNotFoundException, right?